# How to make a field required using JavaScript injector

Tags: nodes, javascript

I have a **field** that is part of a **content type** that I need to make required by using a JavaScript injector.  The reason that I can't just make it required while setting the rules for that field is because I have to parse a string that will display on the same page whether or not I need to make it required.  Any thoughts?

Comment: How sensitive is the form? If you absolutely need to make sure that the field is completed, you need the logic to run server-side. A determined user could easily remove any required attribute you set by javascript, and get through the form submission. I guess you could theoretically send an AJAX request whose callback loads the cached form and updates the `#required` status based on the client-side data, but it'd be quite messy. What's a javascript injector by the way, is that a module?

Comment: @Clive yes, it seems that it's a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector)

Comment: @Clive Yes, it is a module.  I am willing to do everything server side with PHP, but I am rather new to Drupal, do you have any recommendations for how to get going with PHP and module development?

Comment: Thanks @user1527576. Matt, the bible is [here](https://www.drupal.org/module-development), but there is a bit of a learning curve. If you're new to PHP too that's going to make it tricky, I don't remember coming across any articles on learning both at the same time. You kinda need to know PHP before most of module development stuff will make enough sense to use it effectively. Because it's so complex it's difficult to just copy/paste code snippets and have them work without tweaking too. Maybe someone else will be able to point you to a good resource, sorry I don't really have anything

Comment: @Clive, learning PHP is not an issue, I've been programming in PHP for almost a year now.  I'm just not sure how to access fields and everything before a page loads.

Comment: @Matt I think that the JS injector is unnecessary, you just need to create a custom validator for your field. Check if the accepted answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82849/validate-all-instances-of-a-field-programmatically) could fit your needs

Comment: In what situation do you need field to be required?

Answer (score 1):

Matt -

I would recommend looking into `hook_node_validate()`. This is a function hook provided by Drupal core that allows you to add custom validation into the form. While you cannot select "required" from the field UI, perhaps you can validate it here and then return an error if the form doesn't provide the correct information for that specific field.

Other things to investigate: `hook_form_alter()` and `hook_validate` - where you can add custom validation functions into the Drupal form array itself.

Helpful links:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7